# Images imported via import.meta.glob visible in build folder but not showing up

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vite

I just switched from **Vue / Vite** to **Laravel / Vue / Vite** stack. Everything is working fine, static images that are used in vue like this are working great after `npm run build` or after `npm run dev` except image folders that are imported via `import.meta.glob("/resources/images/drivers/2023/*")` into vue component.

These images seems not to be working [image]

Working images have `/build/assets/` path
[image]

If i run `npm run build` these images can be then found in build folder but they still got wrong path in the browser. [image]

vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import eslintPlugin from 'vite-plugin-eslint'
import { NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin } from '@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill'

export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        hmr: {
            host: 'localhost',
        },
        watch: {
            usePolling: true,
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/js/main.js',
                'resources/scss/main.scss'
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
        eslintPlugin(),
    ],
    publicPath: '',
    optimizeDeps: {
        esbuildOptions: {
            // Node.js global to browser globalThis
            define: {
                global: 'globalThis'
            },
            plugins: [
                // eslint-disable-next-line new-cap
                NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin({
                    buffer: true
                })
            ],
        }
    },
    build: {
        assetsInlineLimit: 0
    }
});
```

If I console log these images from whole folder that are imported via `import.meta.glob` i get this: [image]

This works fine if not used with laravel.

Comment: In my case, I used to put the folder name to load images in Laravel.

Comment: In the sources section in the browser, check if the resources are loaded there. That may help.

Answer (score 0):

Check out This . [Processing Static Assets With Vite](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite#blade-processing-static-assets)

you should add the following in your application's resources/js/app.js entry point:

```
import.meta.glob([
  '../images/**',
  '../fonts/**',
]);
```

Comment: Already tried this and it doesn't help